# Read-only file system" with SIP disabled in macOS Catalina

Tags: macos, macos-catalina

I am trying to copy some files from a path to my libs path (/usr/lib), I am trying with sudo cp {my file}/usr/lib/
bit I got this error.

```
/usr/lib/{my_file} Read-only file system
```

I have validated and indeed System Integrity Protection is disabled (SIP) I am using macOs Catalina 10.15.4
I Hope you can help me thanks.

Comment: See this question on Ask Different: [Catalina not allowing to change read/write permissions despite having SIP disabled](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/375603/catalina-not-allowing-to-change-read-write-permissions-despite-having-sip-disabl).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You just should try with

```
sudo mount -uw /
```

it should work

Comment: I think this no longer works:

mount_apfs: volume could not be mounted: Permission denied
mount: / failed with 66

Comment: Yes, I ran into the same problem with BigSur 11.0.1.

Answer (score 2):

I just recently joined stack overflow so I am not able to up-vote the above answer. Using `sudo mount -uw /` definitely works. In my case I needed to add a small script to `/sbin` to overcome an issue with **VMware Tools**. Starting with **macOS Catalina**, disabling **SIP** and then executing this command as root was the answer.

Answer (score 1):

I'm also new to stack exchange, but want to add that

"sudo mount -uw /"   worked.   Thank you @Juanse

In my case, was suffering from the problem of Kernel_Task using more than 500% of CPU on my Mid-2012 15 MacBookPro aka (MacBookPro9,1 ) with quad-code Intel Core i7.

After multiple solutions did not work, I went on to try a solution posted at:  https://discussions.apple.com/thread/8461404?answerId=33657338022#33657338022

Which instructed me to:

- Reboot into recovery mode.
- Select Utilities/Terminal, csrutil disable  , reboot.
- cd:
  /System/Library/Extensions/IOPlatformPluginFamily.kext/Contents/PlugIns/X86PlatformPlugin.kext/Contents/Resources
- move or delete a file based on my version of Mac as listed in the thread.  For my MacBookPro9,1 the file 4B7AC7E43945597E.plist
- Reboot into recovery mode
- Select Utilities/Terminal, csrutil enable , reboot.

The problem with the solution, is that when I tried to "mv 4B7AC7E43945597E.plist ~", or even "sudo mv 4B7AC7E43945597E.plist ~", I got a read-only file system message.  Running "sudo mount -uw /" made the file system writeable.  Note that the steps of booting into recovery mode and disabling / enabling csrutil turned off, and then back on the apple System Integrity Protection (SIP), which is necessary if you wish to change certain key system or configuration files.