# MacOS Catalina read-write mount could not be mounted in single user or recovery mode with permission denied

Tags: macos, macos-catalina

I need to have writable access to the file system in recovery mode, but I always get the error

mount_apfs: volume could not be mounted: Permission denied.

I am aware of others who solved it like this: [Read-only file system" with SIP disabled in macOS Catalina](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61131634/read-only-file-system-with-sip-disabled-in-macos-catalina)

i.e.:

- start in recovery mode (Cmd-R at startup)
- open terminal and disable SIP with `csrutil disable`
- reboot into single user mode (Cmd-S at startup)
- check SIP is disabled with `csrutil status`
- try to mount the volumes with read/write:

```
sudo mount -uw /
sudo mount -uw /System/Volumes/Data
```

Neither of the two volumes can be mounted, I always get permission denied even with SIP disabled.

Interestingly, even if I boot the Mac from an external SSD (in this case an old Sierra installation) I cannot mount the disk as read/write.

Any further suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem in this case was a defect SSD, which switched into readonly mode after only 36 TB written, despite having a design of 1200 TBW.

Unfortunately, MacOS did not report this. When looking at System information > Storage > my SSD > SMART status the system still showed "Verified", which is supposed to mean that everything is ok.

It was not.

I determined this by installing smartmontools and running a check:

```
brew install smartmontools

smartctl -a disk1
```

it showed e.g.:

```
SMART overall-health self-assessment test result: FAILED
- Available spare has fallen below threshold
- media has been placed in read-only mode

- Data Units Written: ... 35,4 TB
- Available Spare: 1%
- Available Spare Threshhold: 10%
```

So issues

1. bad luck with SSD
2. bad error reporting by MacOS